# Need IntelliJ IDEA 9 cheat sheet

Tags: intellij-idea

I searched but couldn't find anything what I can print and put on the wall.

Comment: you only need to know one keystroke really:`CTRL+SHIFT+A` - keep using that and you'll pick up others quickly

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Help -> Default Keymap Reference.

It's a one page pdf, so you should be able to print it out and place on the wall.

Comment: You know, it's funny but that's it. All others are more wordy and too large to be printed.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I believe http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/intellij-idea was what you were looking for.

Comment: That's actually really nice.  My only dings are 1) it's 7 pages, not exactly a cheat "sheet," and 2) it's 3rd-party and thus has the potential to be out of date.

Answer (score 1):

see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/index.jsp (it is applicable to other versions as well I guess)